# Use cases, User Stories, CRC cards and Conceptual Object Model

Tags: object-oriented-design

i'm currently in the middle of watching the Lynda.com course on the foundations of Object Oriented Design and one question keeps popping into my mind.

When should I use Use cases and when should I use User Stories?

And the same question goes for the other part

When should I use CRC cards and when should I use a Conceptual Object Model?

Can I use one and "skip" the other? Are they compliments of each other?

Answer (score 1):

You can use any one that you are comfortable with. "Fully dressed" use cases tend to be more verbose and detailed. User stories, on the other hand, involve input that comes directly from users, and is usually a very short description which is less detailed. That said they push more of the design work into coding phase, which most developers tend to like.

The things about requirements is they change very quickly. User stories are a mainstay of agile and/or test driven development. If you have frequent communication with the stakeholder of the application, and can update the application you are working on every few days to every two weeks, and you can get immediate feedback from your users, then user stories are probably the way to go.

On the other hand, if you are working with some offshore guys who read english better than they speak it, then use cases might be the right fit for that project. Also, if you are working on a more critical app, that could blow something up if it went down the wrong path, then you might need more detailed specs up front.

As far CRC vs COM is concerned, they are both used for design. I personally like CRC and responsibility driven design myself. That said, you can do the same thing with use cases and a UML COM. In the use case + COM case, more design is done outside of coding, which is often end up changing during the coding phase.

If you are doing Test Driven Development (TDD), you will design your code through a series of tests that  guarantee your code meets it's requirements. That way, you are not writing any extra code, just what is needed to meet the requirements.

The most important thing is to get the principles off OOD down. Once you understand that, you can use any method that is comfortable for you.

Scrum is a very popular agile project process used by many teams these days, you might want to look into that:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_(software_development)

Another thing you might want to look into is BDD
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development

Here is an example from the same page of a behavioral specification user story.

```
Story: Returns go to stock

In order to keep track of stock
As a store owner
I want to add items back to stock when they're returned

Scenario 1: Refunded items should be returned to stock
Given a customer previously bought a black sweater from me
And I currently have three black sweaters left in stock
When he returns the sweater for a refund
Then I should have four black sweaters in stock

Scenario 2: Replaced items should be returned to stock
Given that a customer buys a blue garment
And I have two blue garments in stock
And three black garments in stock.
When he returns the garment for a replacement in black,
Then I should have three blue garments in stock
And two black garments in stock
```